# Allow a rigid body to only move in the Y direction.

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics

I am making a 2d game using Unity 4.3. I have a rigidbody2d object. When other physics2d objects hit the rigidbody2d object it moves a little bit in the x direction.

I don't want it to move in the x direction. I want to make the rigidbody2d object's x direction fixed. How can I achieve that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [RigidBody2D freeze X position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579017/rigidbody2d-freeze-x-position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, RigidBody2D is missing a key feature present in RigidBody (3D), [constraints](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-constraints.html).

A workaround could be to always lock your RigidBody2D's position on the X-Axis, although, this may lead to bugs in your physics:

```
void Update() 
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(STATIC_X, transform.position.y, transform.position.x);
}
```

Another option, would be to not use a RigidBody, and attempt to simulate the physics yourself.

Comment: Hi,thanks for your quick response.I already did the code  ..............     function Start () {
 this.rigidbody2D.isKinematic = true;
 positionOfSpike = this.transform.position.x;
}.....function Update () {this.transform.position.x = positionOfSpike;}  ....... but placed in wrong place.Your suggested code also do the same and another solution of my problem.Thanks a lot.